# Portfolio Builder no longer compatible with WordPress 5.7

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I am using the "Modish WP" theme in my WordPress installation. This has two dependencies: one is the Slider Revolution plugin and the other is the Portfolio Builder Modish plugin (from europadns). I was able to update the first one without any problems, the second one is already a few years old and apparently still uses the old jQuery library, which no longer seems to be compatible with WordPress 5.7 and causes conflicts with the blog.

Is there a successor or an alternative for the plugin or can I make the jQuery library compatible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You need a new Portfolio Builder Plugin. You might be able to use the new jQuery library but there is no guarantee that the new library will be compatible with the old code of the plugin.

Comment: Yes, but is there a successor (I think the last version is from 2017) or an alternative with similar functionality?

Comment: I never used the portfolio builder from Modish WP so I don't know what exact functionality you are looking for. But there are many Portfolio Builder plugins available to pick from.